# How do I upload directly to Chart Studio with plotly in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I'd like to access my plotly account in R.

I ran this code:

```
library(plotly)
signup(
    "someusername",
    "someemail@gmail.com"
)
```

And I got back this error

```
Creating/Users/myfolder/.Rprofile
Error in cat_profile("username", con$un) : 
  R doesn't have permission to write to this file: ~
You should consider putting this in an .Rprofile 
(or sourcing it when you use plotly):
```

How do I resolve this error? My goal is to upload directly from R into Plotly Chart Studio with this code

```
gg <-
  iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_col(fill = "green")

ggplotly(gg)

api_create(ggplotly(gg))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find all the information you need on the plotly tutorial linked

https://plotly.com/r/getting-started-with-chart-studio/#getting-started-with-chart-studio-and-the-plotly-r-package

you want to set your chart studio credentials with Sys.Setenv

```
Sys.setenv("plotly_username"="your_plotly_username")
Sys.setenv("plotly_api_key"="your_api_key")
```

you can get your API key in your account settings on chart studio

following this (the example used in the plotly tutorial):

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(midwest, x = ~percollege, color = ~state, type = "box")
api_create(p, filename = "r-docs-midwest-boxplots")
```

api_create() should then publish your plot to chart studio